# DJANGO KeyError when using request.session with form.cleaned_data

Tags: python, html, django

I have 2 view functions. One takes form data and (optimally) stores it in the request.session. The second calls this data and uses it to filter in a search query. I also have 2 html templates that correspond to each of these views. Here are the Views

```
def searchpatients(request):
form = PatientSearchForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    request.session['fdata'] = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
    request.session['ldata'] = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
context = {
    'form_search' : form,
    }
return render(request, 'polls/search.html', context)
```

AND

```
def displayed_try(request):
    fdata = request.session['fdata']
    ldata = request.session['ldata']
    results = Patients.objects.filter(
    first_name__icontains = 'fdata'
    ).filter(
    last_name__icontains = 'ldata'
    ).values_list('first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'status')
    context = {
    'results' : results
    }
    return render(request, 'polls/displayed.html', context)
```

When running the search function, I get a key error like this

```
KeyError at /displayed/
```

'fdata'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/displayed/
Django Version: 2.0.6
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:
'fdata'
Exception Location: C:\Users\msengar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py in **getitem**, line 55
Python Executable:  C:\Users\msengar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.5

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am not sure how to take data from a form (on a distinct HTML template) in Django and use that form data to search and display on another HTML page. For reference, my 2 html pages are search.html (which houses the search form) and displayed.html (which displays the filtered data in a list). The Search page works as intended but the displayed.html page either always gives me some keyerror(when using session storage) or shows an empty table with no data (when using only form action). Lastly, here is the displayed.html code.

```
{% block content %}
<div class = "shit">
<table class="table table-hover indexed table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope = "col"> "First Name" </th>
      <th scope = "col"> "Last Name" </th>
      <th scope = "col"> "Phone" </th>
      <th scope = "col"> "Status" </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody id = "rtable">
    {% for x in results %}
    <tr>
      {% for v in x %}
        <td> {{ v }} </td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

EDIT- this is the urls.py --

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', home_try, name = 'homepage'),
path('signup/', signup_try.as_view(), name = 'signup'),
path('add/', addpatients, name = 'tryadding'),
path('profile/', profile_try, name = 'tryprofile'),
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
path('information/', information_try, name = 'tryinformation'),
path('logout/', logout_try, name = 'tryloggingout'),
path('login/', auth_views.login, name = 'login'),
path('login_error/', login_error_handle, name = 'tryloginerror'),
path('change_password/', auth_views.password_reset, name = 'passwordchangetry'),
path('table_view/', table_try, name = 'try_table'),
path('search/', searchpatients, name = 'try_search'),
path('displayed/', displayed_try, name = 'try_displayed'),
```

AND this is the search.html code --

```
<form method = "POST" action = "../displayed/" name = "pls">
<fieldset>
  <legend> Search Entry </legend>
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form_search.as_p }}
  <button type = "submit"> Search </button>
</fieldset>
```

Thanks guys, and sorry for how disorganized this is. Pls help!

Answer (score 0):

You are storing session value to fdata
`first_name__icontains = fdata` instead of '`fdata`' with quotation

Another tip- use [Q](https://micropyramid.com/blog/querying-with-django-q-objects/) to concatinate query.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! I changed this quotation mistake but it doesn't even look like my form is validating in my searchpatient view. Therefore none of the request.session data is being saved. Why doesnt my form.is_valid come to True? Thanks again!

Comment: You can check if request.method == 'POST' and then check if the form is valid. Put a check point(print something )after post request and after checking if it's valid. also make sure your action url is correct and your form method is post. To get me understand where the err is, can you please attach urls.py and html code of form? I think the problem is there.

Comment: So i did if request.method == POST: run program else: return to home page. And every time i execute the function it returns me to the main page

Comment: Clearly Your Post request is not coming to the view.  I still think action url is the culprit. Can you please provide compelete url instead of ... action = "../displayed/"